# Octave:Incorrect FFT phase spectrum

Tags: signal-processing, fft, octave, phase

A small program that I wrote in octave does not yield desired phase spectrum. The magnitude plot is perfect though.

```
 f = 200;
 fs = 1000;
 phase = pi/3; 
 t = 0: 1/fs: 1;
 sig = sin((2*pi*f*t) + phase);
 sig_fft = fft(sig);

 sig_fft_phase = angle(sig_fft) * 180/pi;

 sig_fft_phase(201)
```

`sig_fft_phase(201)` returns 5.998 (6 degrees) rather than 60 degrees. What am I doing wrong? Is my expectation incorrect?

Comment: This -> https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1139#answer_1625 seems like the answer to the same problem !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, if you generate the frequency axis: (sorry, I don’t have Octave here, so Python will have to do—I’m *sure* it’s the same in Octave):

```
faxis = (np.arange(0, t.size) / t.size) * fs
```

you’ll see that `faxis[200]` (Python is 0-indexed, equivalent to Octave’s 201 index) is **199.80019980019981**. You think you’re asking for the phase at 200 Hz but you’re not, you’re asking for the phase of 199.8 Hz.

(This happens because your `t` vector includes 1.0—that one extra sample slightly decreases the spectral spacing! I *don’t* think the link @Sardar_Usama posted in their comment is correct—it has nothing to do with the fact that the sinusoid doesn’t end on a complete cycle, since this approach *should* work with incomplete cycles.)

The solution: zero-pad the 1001-long `sig` vector to 2000 samples. Then, with a new `faxis` frequency vector, `faxis[400]` (Octave’s 401st index) corresponds to exactly 200 Hz:

```
In [54]: sig_fft = fft.fft(sig, 2000);

In [55]: faxis = np.arange(0, sig_fft.size) / sig_fft.size * fs

In [56]: faxis[400]
Out[56]: 200.0

In [57]: np.angle(sig_fft[400]) * 180 / np.pi
Out[57]: -29.950454729683386
```

But oh no, what happened? This says the angle is -30°?

Well, recall that [Euler’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry) says that `sin(x) = (exp(i * x) - exp(-i * x)) / 2i`. That `i` in the denominator means that the phase recovered by the FFT won’t be 60°, even though the input sine wave has phase of 60°. Instead, the FFT bin’s phase will be `60 - 90` degrees, since -90° = `angle(1/i) = angle(-i)`. So this is actually the right answer! To recover the sine wave’s phase, you’d need to add 90° to the phase of the FFT bin.

So to summarize, you need to fix two things:

1. make sure you’re looking at the right frequency bin. For an `N`-point FFT (and no `fftshift`), the bins are `[0 : N - 1] / N * fs`. Above, we just used a N=2000 point FFT to ensure that 200 Hz be represented.
2. Understand that, although you have a sine wave, as far as the FFT is concerned, it gets two complex exponentials, at +200 and -200 Hz, and with amplitudes 1/(2i) and -1/(2i). That imaginary value in the denominators shifts the phase you expect by -90° and +90° respectively.

   - *If you happened to have used `cos`, a cosine wave, for `sig`, you wouldn’t have run into this mathematical obstacle , so pay attention to the difference between sin and cos in the future !*

Comment: If it was not for sin, I wouldn't have learnt so many things today. :-). By the way, I simply reduced the number of samples in my original program by 1 [0 to 1 - 1/fs] and got -30. Which matches the Euler derivation. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

change to `t=0:1/fs:1-1/fs;` then

```
 sig_fft_phase(201)
 ans = -30.000
```